# Disable anchor ads at the top of your page on amp-auto-ads

Tags: ads, amp-html, adsense-anchor-ads

Here an instruction [https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7478225?hl=en](https://Here%20an%20instruction%20https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7478225?hl=en%20for%20non%20amp%20pages.%20%20I%20couldn%27t%20find%20anything%20for%20amp-auto-ads.%20%20Does%20anyone%20have%20experience%20with%20this.) for non **amp pages**.

I couldn't find anything for [**amp-auto-ads**](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-auto-ads/?format=websites).

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Site Kit plugin and allowed it to insert ads, this might be the reason.

Google Site Kit automatically places auto ads for AMP and non-AMP version of website. In this case the user doesn't need to insert ads code manually.

If you don't want this behaviour then you can disable it from the Site Kit plugin setting for AdSense: Settings → Connected services → Adsense → Edit